# Sklearn error: 'SVR' object has no attribute '_impl'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

What I'm doing:
I am trying to forecast data using a tested (pickled) SVM regression model that was built on another machine. The scaling works fine, but even trying to forecast based on the original learning sample fails with the same error.

> 'SVR' object has no attribute '_impl'

The error occurs on a WIN 7 64bit workstation with Python 2.7.5, Numpy 1.7.1 (MKL) and sklearn (scikit-learn 0.14.1). Both are 64bit.

EDIT:

Below is the code. And it worked on the machine that did the learning bit.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn import preprocessing
import cPickle as cp
import numpy as np
model = cp.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
scaler = cp.load(open('scaler.pkl', 'rb'))
theData = np.genfromtxt(open('inputData.csv','rb'), delimiter=',')
scaledXs = scaler.transform( theData )
result = model.predict( scaledXs )
```

EDIT 2:
FYI: The learning part was done on piCloud which uses the 0.13.1 version. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Post your code, have you tried the SVR example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html

Comment: You can follow the discussion here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15902 A workaround that worked for me was changing the sklearn SVM library's _base.py file using this link https://ibex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn/svm/base.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It appears that **the model generated on piCloud using sklearn 0.13.1 is not compatible with the 0.14.1 library** !

Since the AMD64 0.13.1 binary is nowhere to be found, I ended up re-learning the model using the 0.14.1 library on the new machine, and it now works fine. I also tried running the old model on the a machine that had the 0.13.1 library and it worked fine.

Comment: This a well-known problem with scikit-learn (actually with `pickle` in general): any refactoring may break pickled objects.