# Python error in SVM classifier.predict()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am getting the following error when i perform classification of new data with the following command in Python:

```
classifier.predict(new_data)
```

AttributeError: python 'SVC' object has no attribute _dual_coef_

In my laptop though, the command works fine! What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same version on both computers ?

Comment: yes. It is really weird cause its a basic function of the scikit learn toolkit

Comment: Can you provide input that causes the error?

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact error 
`AttributeError: python 'SVC' object has no attribute _dual_coef_` 
with a model trained using scikit-learn version 0.15.2, when I tried to run it in scikit-learn version 0.16.1. I did solve it by re-training the model in the latest scikit-learn 0.16.1.

Make sure you are loading the right version of the package.

Comment: Too bad old saved models won't run on newer versions... hope there is be a more safe data format in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the model based on which you try to predict?
In this case it can be a version conflict, try to re-learn the model using the same sklearn version.
You can see a similar problem here: [Sklearn error: 'SVR' object has no attribute '_impl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089386/sklearn-error-svr-object-has-no-attribute-impl)

Comment: yes, everything is loaded. I am using the same programming pipeline in both computers

Comment: Did you tried (or do you have the possibility ) to inverse the computers roles for model construction and prediction?

Comment: unfortunately this cannot be done in the present configuration of the computers and the present datasets

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,I use Sklearn version 0.23.02 but I was trying to run an archive trained with a version 0.18... and my error said: "'SVC' object has no attribute 'break_ties'", I just retrained the model with my version and fix the problem I generate other svc.pickle to run with the  0.23.02 version and replace the oldie.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
X = X_train 
y =  y_train 
"""
X = X_test 
y =  y_test

# Instantiate and train the classifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
clf.fit(X, y) 


# Check the results using metrics
from sklearn import metrics
y_pred = clf.predict(X)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_pred, y))
```